# how to create a server in react with express or http?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http

I'm building a web app with react js
i want to create a server for client in my project
so i'm using express or http
I tried this code

```
import React from "react";
var  express = require("express"); // I also used with import
const app = express();
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
      res.end("hello world");
      }).listen(8000, ()=>{
        alert("server started")
      });
}
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/*....*/}
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But it throw a error

then i tried with http

```
import React from "react";
var  http = require("http");

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    http.createServer((req,res)=>{
      res.end("hello world");
      }).listen(8000, ()=>{
        alert("server started")
      });
}
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/*....*/}
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

it also throw a error
what should i do?
how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an express server you have to use Node.js.

You cannot create an express server with react.

You have to install Node.js, take a look: https://nodejs.org/en/
(I recommend you to install the "Recommended For Most Users" version, for now: 14.15.4)

Then follow this tutorial: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: is there any module for react that create a server like express?

Comment: @RajmaniKumar Hey, no. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to develop a editor with live server using react in monaca

Comment: @RajmaniKumar Ok, and why do you want to build a server?

Comment: yes i want create a server for client to run a local http server

Comment: @RajmaniKumar Yea, but why? maybe it can be done on the client-side.

Comment: to preview html files in browser

Comment: @RajmaniKumar So follow the basic tutorial that I've mentioned. Learn more about Node.js, good luck! :) If you found my answer useful, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: is there any way to execute a node js file in client side in react

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is not possible. React is a client-based framework that relies on the browser DOM, while Express and HTTP servers are Node.js libraries. They require a Node runtime to run, which can't be provided by React or client based javascript in general.

If you want to host a React app in Express, you need to run Express on a Node.js server first. Take a look at @shai_sharakanski's answer for that.